# SHA1 encryption trouble

Tags: c#, database, encryption

I have a problem with the password encryption.
I would like to have the password encrypted like those not highlighted in the picture.

I wrote the following c# code:

```
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider x = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

        //byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        //byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
        var s = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in bs)
        {
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }

        new UserService().ChangeUserPassword(username, s.ToString());
```

to encrypt the password in the correct way I using the following SQL code that I want remove:

> `CAST(hashbytes('SHA1',@newuserpassword) as nvarchar)`

this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Storing binary data in characters is not safe. You will experience random data loss and weird bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), I suspect you just want:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar, hashbytes('SHA1',@newuserpassword), 2)
```

Where 2 is the style which converts to hex without a leading 0x. I suggest you specify the length of the `nvarchar` though, which should be 40 (20 bytes, 2 characters per byte).

Comment: tnx but I need to have the same result in c#. I mean I want the password in my db with the chinese characters

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio: You really don't. That output is simply *broken*. It's trying to represent arbitrary binary data as text in an inappropriate way. **Don't do it.** Use hex or base64. If you've currently got data stored in that format, you should assume it's garbage.

Comment: I guess it is possible to salvage enough data so that password validation can be performed with high-enough accuracy. But the OP should abandon this scheme asap.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to abandon storing binary data in characters. Still, if you need to keep it for legacy reasons, here is the translation of the SQL statement:

```
byte[] bytes = ...; //your binary data here
var nastilyBrokenChars =
    Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length / 2)
    .Select(i => (char)BitConverter.GetInt16(bytes, i * 2))
    .ToArray();
string nastilyBrokenString = new string(nastilyBrokenChars);
```

As you can, I'm stuffing two `bytes` into each `char`. This by itself is a lossless conversion. But I **wouldn't trust** that storing this data into SQL Server (and comparing it later) is loss-less.